# Java Swing - How to sound beep before any JOptionPane?

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane, beep

Whenever i show a JOptionPane in my Swing application i fire a beep before it like this :

```
Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep();
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( myFrame, "Message", "Title", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE );
```

**Is there a way to apply the first line automatically to any JOptionPane in case i forgot to write it in code ?**

Comment: Are you sure you really want to do that? Beep every time a popup is shown?

Comment: @fish ... Yes, My users are blind, so i want them to hear the beeeeeeeep :)

Comment: Curious why java doesn't have "\a"

Comment: @user489041 System.out.print("\007") may work, but it buzzes (mainboard) instead of beep afaik.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could create your own class which has a static method `showMessageDialogAndBeep()` which calls `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog` and beeps before.

Comment: I was looking for AlexR's solution, but i couldn't implement it. I will use the normal solution then. Thanks atamanroman.

Answer (score 2):

`void showMessageDialog(Component pC, Object m, String t, int mT)
{
Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep();
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( pC, m,t,mT);
}`

Answer (score 0):

I agree with org.life.java and atamanroman. 
Additionally I can suggest you the following.  Create AWTListener and register it using

```
Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().addAWTEventListener(listener, eventMask)
```

I think that this listener will be called in many cases including dialog opening. So you just have to recognize the case and call `beep()`. I did not try this but I believe it will work.

Comment: . I know this may not be safe, but that's what i'm looking for. Can you please give me an example ? ... I'm trying to apply this on JOptionPane.showMessageDialog() or JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog()